# laravel insert data using DB:Transaction

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have simple Laravel upload, insert/update.

I have ajax that uploads csv file to my directory..

```
$.ajax({
    url:'uploadExcel',
    data: new FormData($("#uploadForm")[0]),
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    },
    // dataType:'json',
    async: true,
    type:'post',
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false, 
    success: function(){
        //chunk data from CSV
    },
    error: function(data){
        var errors = data.responseJSON;
        console.log(errors);
    },
    complete:function(completeData){
        console.log(completeData);
    }
});
```

After success, I chunk the data from csv. It chunks successfully using this [link](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) and now I'm using `DB::transaction(function() {});` in inserting to database. But now i want to use the `DB:COMMIT` and `DB:ROLLBACK`...

Any idea on how I can do this?

For `DB:COMMIT` I have a button that commits the last transaction.

For `DB:ROLLBACK` I have a button that rolls everything back in the last transaction.

***note: I'm doing ajax for this and it does not work.***

*Update*: I do the manual way.
 I have a function for `beginTransaction`

```
DB::beginTransaction();
    foreach($results as $row){
        $item = new items;
        $selectQuery = DB::table('items')
            ->where('title', '=', $row["1"])
            ->where('description', '=', $row["2"])
            ->get();

        if (count($selectQuery) > 0) {
            // update
            DB::table('items')
                ->where('title', '=', $row["1"])
                ->where('description', '=', $row["2"])
                ->update([
                    "title" => $row["1"],
                    "description" => $row["2"]
                ]);

        } else {
            //insert
            $item->title = $row["1"];
            $item->description = $row["2"];
            $item->save();
        } 
    }
```

and my 2nd function in my controller is  `DB::commit();` and the 3rd function is for `DB:rollback();`.

This method does not save any data from csv and rollback and commit are not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't you be wrapping this within a `try-catch`?  Put `DB::beginTransaction()` and `DB::commit()` inside the try block and `DB::rollback()` inside the catch block. Why have buttons for rollback and commit?

Comment: @Doom5 because i want 1st to check if the data in csv is correct and to do  this i want 1st to save it to database and have 2 separate buttons for the commit() and rollback()

Comment: Then you should be validating it first before saving it to the database. Also, it seems like you are doing an update or insert saving pattern.

Comment: Offtopic, but it's bad practice and a performance loss to SELECT the rows you are going to update anyway. Just do $updated = DB::table...->update(...); and if no rows were updated, then INSERT.

Comment: @AiXEn can you confirm if your function is throwing any error ?

Answer (score 1):

If you pass a Closure to `DB::transaction()`, Laravel will auto call `DB::commmit` if no the Closure executes successfully and `DB::rollBack` if an exception is being thrown.

If you want to have control over it (the manual way), use `DB::beginTransaction()`

For example:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try{
   ...

   DB::commit();
}catch(\Exception $e){
   // echo $e->getMessage();
   DB::rollBack();
}
```

Comment: I do the manual way i use `DB::beginTransaction()` so i have 3 function in controller 1st function is for `beginTransaction()` the 2nd function is for `Commit` and the 3rd function  is for `Rollback` and still im not able to rollback the last transaction...

Answer (score 1):

> Laravel: Database Transactions

If you're using transaction method on the DB facade and If an exception is thrown within the transaction Closure, the transaction will automatically be rolled back. If the Closure executes successfully, the transaction will automatically be committed. You don't need to worry about manually rolling back or committing while using the transaction method:

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    //your queries
});
```

**Manually Using Transactions**

If you would like to begin a transaction manually and have complete control over rollbacks and commits, you may use the beginTransaction method on the DB facade:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
```

You can rollback the transaction via the rollBack method:

```
DB::rollBack();
```

Lastly, you can commit a transaction via the commit method:

```
DB::commit();
```

For more detail go to docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#database-transactions

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. Define a separate connection for this purpose in your `config/database.php` lets say `temporary_connection`.
Now, in your Controller, instead of using transaction on `DB`(it uses default connection) use the newly created connection.

Your method containing `beginTransaction`:

```
$connection = DB::connection('temporary_connection');
$connection->beginTransaction();
//rest of the code
```

Your method containing `rollback`:

```
$connection = DB::connection('temporary_connection');
$connection->rollback();
//rest of the code
```

Your method containing `commit`:

```
$connection = DB::connection('temporary_connection');
$connection->commit();
//rest of the code
```